# How can I check if something to read in asyncio StreamReader in Windows and Python 3.7+?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.7

I try to communicate with Stockfish (it is stdin/stdout application).

It works like that:

1. I send some line into stdin.
2. It response with some lines into stdout at once.
3. It can response continuously with next lines (new move evaluation).
4. Stockfish should never stops so `communicate()` will not work since not designer for it. `add_reader` not work in Windows.

It is sending unpredicted number of lines and continuously.

The problem is when I call `await stdout.readline()` is it blocking for program flow by I do not want block flow but check if new line is read to read. How can I read lines without blocking.

Some code which I do - nothing complex:

```
import asyncio

import sys


def stockfish_read_stdout(line):
    print(line)


async def run_stockfish():
    STOCKFISH_PATH = r'C:\root\chess\stockfish\stockfish 9\stockfish_9_x64_bmi2.exe'

    stockfish = await asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_exec(
        STOCKFISH_PATH,
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)

    # It is maybe not work since output is not complete.
    stockfish.stdin.write('uci'.encode())

    # How to check if line read to read?
    # I put True but here should be check.
    while True:
        line = await stockfish.stdout.readline()
        print(line)

    await stockfish.wait()


if sys.platform == "win32":
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(
        asyncio.WindowsProactorEventLoopPolicy())

asyncio.run(run_stockfish(), debug=True)
```

Output is:

```
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
runfile('C:/Users/Cezary Wagner/PycharmProjects/stockfish-proxy/sandbox/async_proxy/s01_async_stockfish.py', wdir='C:/Users/Cezary Wagner/PycharmProjects/stockfish-proxy/sandbox/async_proxy')
b'Stockfish 9 64 BMI2 by T. Romstad, M. Costalba, J. Kiiski, G. Linscott\r\n'
```

But should be after `uci`:

```
Stockfish 9 64 BMI2 by T. Romstad, M. Costalba, J. Kiiski, G. Linscott
uci
id name Stockfish 9 64 BMI2
id author T. Romstad, M. Costalba, J. Kiiski, G. Linscott

option name Debug Log File type string default
option name Contempt type spin default 20 min -100 max 100
option name Threads type spin default 1 min 1 max 512
option name Hash type spin default 16 min 1 max 131072
option name Clear Hash type button
option name Ponder type check default false
option name MultiPV type spin default 1 min 1 max 500
option name Skill Level type spin default 20 min 0 max 20
option name Move Overhead type spin default 30 min 0 max 5000
option name Minimum Thinking Time type spin default 20 min 0 max 5000
option name Slow Mover type spin default 89 min 10 max 1000
option name nodestime type spin default 0 min 0 max 10000
option name UCI_Chess960 type check default false
option name SyzygyPath type string default 
option name SyzygyProbeDepth type spin default 1 min 1 max 100
option name Syzygy50MoveRule type check default true
option name SyzygyProbeLimit type spin default 6 min 0 max 6
uciok
```

Comment: Should `'uci'.encode()` be `'uci\n'.encode()` or, more simply, `b'uci\n'`?

Comment: Can be probably but I am not sure so not I am not using I will check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a separate coroutine which will read the lines from process's stdout buffer, because `await` blocks the *current* coroutine execution until result is received.

```
async def reader(process, msg_handler, exit_handler):
    while not process.stdout.at_eof():
        line = await process.stdout.readline()
        msg_handler(line.decode())
    # Finished
    exit_handler()
```

Now you can run it as a task in the event loop.

```
async def run_stockfish():
    STOCKFISH_PATH = r'C:\root\chess\stockfish\stockfish 9\stockfish_9_x64_bmi2.exe'

    stockfish = await asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_exec(
        STOCKFISH_PATH,
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)

    # It is maybe not work since output is not complete.
    stockfish.stdin.write('uci\n'.encode())

    task = asyncio.create_task(reader(stockfish,
                                      lambda msg: print(f'Output: {msg}'),
                                      lambda: print('EOF'))

    # asyncio.create_task won't block this coroutine
```

Hope it's not too late.

Comment: I need test it looks promising.

Comment: @Chameleon can you please mark this as a correct answer if it works for you.